# Matrix Invertibility Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that $AB = A + B$, and let $I_n$ denote the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Show that the matrix $I_n - A$ is invertible, with inverse given by $I_n - B$

My initial thought process)

$$AB - B = A$$

$$I_n - AB - B$$

Comment: hmm... I tried editing the post but I can't decipher the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(I_n - A)(I_n - B)$ = $I_nI_n - I_nB - AI_n - AB$ = $I_n - A - B + AB$. Now we know that $AB = A+ B$ so $\implies$ $(I_n - A)(I_n - B) = I_n - A - B + A + B = I_n$. Since $(I_n-A)$ has a right inverse, and is square, this means that $(I_n - A)$ is invertible and clearly $(I_n-B)$ is its inverse. In general, for *square* matrices, the existence of a right or left inverse implies the other as well and implies invertibility.